# Weird Exception in HDF5

Tags: c++, hdf5

I was trying a basic hdf5 dataset read/write operations in C++.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "h5cpp.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#ifndef H5_NO_NAMESPACE
    using namespace H5;
#endif

const H5std_string  fName("dset.h5");
const H5std_string  dsName("dset");

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int data[10];
        int dataOut[10];
        //Exception::dontPrint();

        std::cout<<"Enter The Data : ";
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
            std::cin>>data[i];

        H5File file(fName, H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
        IntType type(H5T_NATIVE_INT);

        Group *myGroup = new Group(file.createGroup("\\myGroup"));

        hsize_t dim[] = {10};
        DataSpace dSpace(1,dim);

        DataSet dSet = myGroup->createDataSet(dsName, type, dSpace);
        dSet.write(data, type);

        std::cout << "Data Written\n";
        dSet.read(dataOut, type);

        std::cout<<"Data Read\n";
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++)
            std::cout<<dataOut[i]<<"\n";

        delete myGroup;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printError();
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

After all the data is entered, I get exceptions:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.12) thread 0:
#000: ..\..\src\H5F.c line 1503 in H5Fcreate(): unable to create file
major: File accessibilty
minor: Unable to open file
#001: ..\..\src\H5F.c line 1285 in H5F_open(): unable to open file: time = Wed
Feb 12 00:02:29 2014
, name = '@╦>ÿK', tent_flags = 13
major: File accessibilty
minor: Unable to open file
#002: ..\..\src\H5FD.c line 987 in H5FD_open(): open failed
major: Virtual File Layer
minor: Unable to initialize object
#003: ..\..\src\H5FDsec2.c line 343 in H5FD_sec2_open(): unable to open file:
name = '@╦>ÿK', errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', flags = 13, o_fl
ags = 302
major: File accessibilty
minor: Unable to open file
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.12) thread 0:
#000: ..\..\src\H5F.c line 1503 in H5Fcreate(): unable to create file
major: File accessibilty
minor: Unable to open file
#001: ..\..\src\H5F.c line 1285 in H5F_open(): unable to open file: time = Wed
Feb 12 00:02:29 2014
, name = '@╦>ÿK', tent_flags = 13
major: File accessibilty
minor: Unable to open file
#002: ..\..\src\H5FD.c line 987 in H5FD_open(): open failed
major: Virtual File Layer
minor: Unable to initialize object
#003: ..\..\src\H5FDsec2.c line 343 in H5FD_sec2_open(): unable to open file:
name = '@╦>ÿK', errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', flags = 13, o_fl
ags = 302
major: File accessibilty
minor: Unable to open file
```

But if I hardcode the filename and dataset names like "abcd.h5" and "dSet", then, I am able to get to get the required output but after the output, I am getting exceptions:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.12) thread 0:
#000: ..\..\src\H5T.c line 1765 in H5Tclose(): immutable datatype
major: Invalid arguments to routine
minor: Bad value
DataType::~DataType - H5Tclose failed
```

Please, help me in figuring out this problem.

Comment: Just a style comment: why do you use a pointer for `myGroup`? This is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

There are two distinct problems. The first one is that somehow, `H5std_string` which is in fact just a `std::string` gets mangled on your system. It seems that `dset.h5` is transformed into `@╦>ÿK`. I might be wrong but that's how it looks. For this I have no clue, it's a Windows issue and to be honest, it's a bit scary.

The second problem problem comes from `type`: the destructor complains that it cannot destroy this object since it is immutable. So why is it immutable? Because you are using [this constructor](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/classH5_1_1IntType.html#a9e5ddb1a36be05d38ae6c64a119c6add):

```
H5::IntType::IntType(const hid_t existing_id)
```

which just wraps the immutable `H5T_NATIVE_INT` type, instead of [this one](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/classH5_1_1IntType.html#ae490ae5914c745c2b37a4909413b8f44):

```
H5::IntType::IntType(const PredType& pred_type)
```

which **clones** `H5T_NATIVE_INT`, and the clone is mutable and more importantly, *can* be destroyed. So you need to replace:

```
IntType type(H5T_NATIVE_INT);
```

by

```
IntType type(PredType::NATIVE_INT);
```

and you will be good.

Comment: You can event get rid of `type` completely and use `PredType::NATIVE_INT` directly in your `dSet.read` and `dSet.write`.

Comment: The second part really helped me out, where can I find thihngs like that? Thanks ;)